# Visual Studio Code, error with SPGo. It does not work

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-code

I am trying to download a project to my local environment with SPgo. Once I declare all the remote folders and start downloading, Visual Code is forever populating the workspace and doesn't update anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please modify the "remoteFolders" path patterns to

```
    "remoteFolders": [
            "/SiteAssets/**/*",
            "/Paginas/**/*"
        ]
```

and recheck. I hope it will help :)